# How to store IEnumerable<> data values in SQL table in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ienumerable, html-agility-pack

I am using the HtmlAgilityPack to retrieve information from a web page and, at present, am using it to show values on the page itself using a ListView control in a button click method.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string url = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
     var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
     var document = webGet.Load(url);
     // Below code crawl the data and store in generic IEnumerable<T> fashion //
     var TheWeb = 
           from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']//div[@class='media-data']")
           from link in info.SelectNodes("h4//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
           from content in info.SelectNodes("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
           from author in info.SelectNodes("p[@class='article-meta']//a[@rel='author']").Where(z => z.Attributes.Contains("href"))
           from date in info.SelectNodes("p[@class='article-meta']//span")
           select new
           {
                 LinkURL = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
                 Text = content.InnerText,
                 Author = author.InnerText,
                 Date = date.InnerText
           };
     lvLinks.DataSource = TheWeb;
     lvLinks.DataBind(); 
}
```

But now I want to store the data in SQL Server and want to run the code using some function (instead of button click).

For that I want to store the data in some other form instead of an IEnumerable<> style which uses LINQ to extract values.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a custom class with the structure

```
public class ParseData
{
    public string LinkURL { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } 
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Populate it with your query

```
var TheWeb = 
       from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']//div[@class='media-data']")
       from link in info.SelectNodes("h4//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
       from content in info.SelectNodes("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
       from author in info.SelectNodes("p[@class='article-meta']//a[@rel='author']").Where(z => z.Attributes.Contains("href"))
       from date in info.SelectNodes("p[@class='article-meta']//span")
       select new ParseData
       {
             LinkURL = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
             Text = content.InnerText,
             Author = author.InnerText,
             Date = date.InnerText
       };
var parseData = TheWeb.ToList();
```

And now using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` serialize this data in XML. Store this XML in your DB and retrieve when ever required.

[Tutorial explaining how to Serialize object in XML and Deserialize back to object](http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2007/07/20/114076.aspx).

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Least interfering way:

```
var IcanbeQueried = myIEnumerable.AsQueryable();
```

Then you can keep the code you have, you only have to convert it to an IQueryable like so.